# What classes can be used as a key in NSDictionary?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, foundation

Can we use only NSString objects as key in an NSDictionary? How do we know which objects can be used and which cannot?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDictionary_Class/Reference/Reference.html):

> In general, a key can be any object (provided that it conforms to the `NSCopying` protocol), but note that when using key-value coding the key must be a string (see [“Key-Value Coding Fundamentals”](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/BasicPrinciples.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002170)).

So you can use anything copyable besides strings, but they'll be problematic with KVC. I just use strings for keys to keep things safe, consistent and simple.

Answer (score 2):

You can use anything that conforms to NSCopying.  That is, you can use `id` - type objects, as long as they conform to `NSCoding` protocol.

In instances where the key is NSString, then isEqualToString: is called for retrieval.  Otherwise, isEqual: is called on the object to determine whether the key matches the requested key.

The key (and value for that matter) cannot be `nil` or `NULL`. They can, however, be `[NSNull null]`.

Comment: Why do people bother asking a question and never returning to check the answer?

Comment: While you _can_ use `NSNull` as a key in a dictionary, it's a singleton, so you can't have more than one entry with that key. It's really intended as a placeholder for empty values.

Comment: @Josh Same goes for any key.  You can only have one NSString key.  Otherwise it wouldn't make sense that a key "key" could be referencing two values, would it?  In that case you'd still have a single key (even NSNull) and have the value be an NSArray.

Comment: Yes, you're right of course; any given string can only be used once as a key. I read your post as implying that multiple `NSNull` instances could be used («_They_ can, however, be...»), but I seem to have been mistaken.

Comment: No prob.  For clarification, I was referring to the key and value by the word "they".